# PHP cURL how to check if compiled?

Tags: iis, php

I'm trying to get the cURL extension for PHP working in IIS.

If in my php.ini file there is no `;extension=php_curl.dll`, does that mean that PHP has not been compiled with cURL?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a PHP script that contains `phpinfo()` and look for a section named **curl**. If it exists then the cURL extension exists, and the section will give you information about the specific version of cURL it has been built against.

Comment: in phpinfo() it appears in the 'Path' bit as 'C:\Program Files\curl-7.19.5' but there is not a separate entry for it.

Answer (score 0):

No it just means that PHP is set to not use the curl module. Remove the ; and restart your webserver and you will be able to use curl with php

Comment: But ensure the dll does actually exist first.

Comment: Thanks for your response, what I mean is, that line wasn't in my php.ini file at all. I've added it and restarted IIS, but it's not working.

Comment: Yep the php_curl.dll is in the etx folder with the rest of the extensions

Comment: did you remove the ; in front of it?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it... I was editing the php.ini file located in c:\program files\php. And it was actually using a different php.ini file located in the Windows folder. Not sure why there would be two of them, but it's all sorted now!